# Why shader name in inspector not the same name as a file?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is what is going on, I have three shaders - `UnlitTexture.shader`, `UnlitTextureYUV.shader` and `YUV420Unlit.shader`, then I try to add `YUV420Unlit` to my material, but problem is that I don't have this shader name in list of shaders, instead I have twice `UnlitTextureYUV` like on screenshot

[image]

What is a problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shader file includes the name of the shader it represents. You find it in the first line and it looks like this:

`Shader "Folder/ShaderName" {`

Unity lists the shaders according to this name, not according to their filenames. If you have multiple shaders with the same full qualifying name you (and Unity) cannot distinguish those.

Comment: Thanks!:) Is folder name required here? I mean if my files has such syntax - `Shader "ShaderName"`, is it ok?

Comment: No, the "folder" name is generally used to group stuff like "all unlit shaders" or "all transparent shaders" and unity reflects it in the inspector structure when selecting the shader manually